# Tensorflow-gpu doesn't working with Nvidia driver 455.45 & CUDA version - 11.1 on UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: tensorflow, installation, tensorflow2.0, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install the latest version of TensorFlow 2 using `pip install tensorflow` as of mentioned in [official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install). I've the latest version of **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**. And my laptop has **Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050ti** graphics card. But when I install Nvidia driver, it only installs the latest **version - 455.45** and its **CUDA version - 11.1.**

Then I installed cuda-toolkit 10.1 and CuDNN7.6. **But still TensorFlow doesn't detect GPU on my system.**

Help me to install TensorFlow on the latest version of Ubuntu and Nvidia Driver.

If you find any blogpost which shows the proper way to install it, please share it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply do a clean install of CUDA (First delete all of its traces and then try to reinstall the correct version, which is `10.1`).

**OR:-** you can install Miniconda or Anaconda on your computer and then run this command on `cmd` :-

`conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu`

which would automatically download and install all the correct software needed to run TensorFlow on GPU.

Comment: Thank you. It really worked for me. Probably the easiest way I found till now to install tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: @ManthanSolanki Good to hear that. If you found my answer helpful, be sure to click the tick button to accept it!